# How can I get a list of templates in the vSphere Rest api

Tags: rest, vsphere

I'm using the vSphere rest api to communicate to my hypervisor.  I'm able to get the list of VMs and turn them on and off with out a problem.
Now I'm trying to get the list of templates, however I don't see how to do that.  According to the documentation here https://developer.vmware.com/apis/vsphere-automation/latest/vcenter/api/vcenter/vm-template/library-items/template_library_item/get/

I need to do a Get on this URL
https://{api_host}/api/vcenter/vm-template/library-items/{template_library_item}

The problem is I don't know what the template_library_item is, so I can't build this URL.

Where can I get the list of template library items?